# C# regular Expression that allows only alphabets and numbers but not any special characters or spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to validate a textbox that should accept strings like 'ab123cd' , 'xy12345', 'a567891'. How can I write a regular expression to meet this requirement? The Length of the accepting string should not exceed 7 characters. Should not allow any Special characters or spaces within the string.

```
while(textbox.text does not match the requirement)
{
MessageBox.Show("Please enter Valid string");
prompt.ShowDialog();  //displaying a Dialog box that shows a textbox  
}
```

Also help me writing the code as shown above. 
Thank You !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check for special characters are not allowed in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062911/check-for-special-characters-are-not-allowed-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
UPDATED
You can try this

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,7}$
```

Explanation:

1. `^` marks start position
2. `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` looks ahead to see if there is any alphabet
3. `(?=.*[0-9]`) looks ahead to see if there is any number
4. `[a-zA-Z0-9]` means any character between a-z , A-Z or 0-9
5. `{1,7}` means can only occur 1-7 times
6. `$` marks end of the string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIJ3I7/8)

Comment: Hi Rizwan! I tried this but it is accepting '1234567' , 'abcdefg' also but I need to restrict it to accept alphanumeric strings only like 'a123456' or 'abc1234' or itcan be 'abc123d'

Comment: @SuryaPrakashKamarthi I have updated the answer, please have a look

Comment: @Thank You Rizwan!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
`^\w{1,7}$`

Means between one and seven alphanumerical chars. You can easily adjust length limits.

If you prefer a greater control other allowed characters, use :
`^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,7}$`, because \w is more permissive so be careful

For C#, you can use the Regex.IsMatch method : Regex.IsMatch méthode (System.Text.RegularExpressions) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Very simple to use.

Comment: \w includes _ as well and it may vary upon regex compilers .

Comment: Next time please read answers until end before jumping on -1 red button. Or maybe you could post your own useful answer.